# Java SQL Insert Multiple variables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, variables, insert

i'm working at my uni project and i have to make a classbook for a local school.My problem is that i want to insert multiple grades into the grades field.I've tought about making an integer array of the jtestfield.getText() and then converting it to a string so i can insert it into table.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
      "UPDATE elev SET fizica=? WHERE nume=? AND prenume=?");

//  nota1=Integer.parseInt(nota.getText());
//  ps.setInt(1, nota1);
    String sir=nota.getText();
    int[] result = Arrays.stream(sir.split(","))
                     .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    String note=Arrays.toString(result).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|\\s", "");
    ps.setString(1,note);
    ps.setString(2,text.getText());
    ps.setString(3, text1.getText());
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

This is the portion of the code but i keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: That's not how these things are done. The classical way to do this is to have a secondary table with a foreign key to the student table, containing a row for each grade. Some databases allow arrays. The table needs to be defined with `fizica` as an array, and then you can use `setArray()` in `PreparedStatement`. It's harder to query with arrays, though.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tought about making an integer array...

Don't.

The simplest solution is to use a 1:n relationship between the table `elev` and a new one `score`. Then you can store many scores in the second table.